# Generalization of a probability property

Tags: probability

Suppose that $P\subseteq\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is a property about pairs of natural numbers. For each fix natural number $b$, define 
$$A_n^b= \{ a\in\{1, \cdots , n\} : (a, b)\in P\}.$$
Equip $A_n^b$ with the uniform probability measure. For each arbitrary natural number $b$, we have 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n^b) = 1.$$
Now, consider 
$$A_n = \{ (a,b)\in\{1, \cdots , n\}\times\{1, \cdots, n\} : (a, b)\in P\},$$ with the uniform probability measure also. I just want to know, is it possible to prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n) = 1.$$

Comment: "Equip $A_n^b$ with the uniform probability measure." If we do that, then $P(A_n^b)=1$ by definition... Do you mean we equip $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$ with the probability measure? So $$P(A_n^b) = \frac{|A_n^b|}{n}?$$

Comment: Let me explain what difficulty may arise. we can write $P(A_n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum P(A_n^b)$. Each of the terms of the previous sum goes to 1 as $n$ goes to infinity, but I am not sure we can deduce that the average of them can go to 1 as well!

Comment: Instead of "explaining what difficulty may arise", can you adress the comment I gave before?

Comment: @5xum Yes. Exactly.

Comment: Then I suggest you edit your question accordingly. It is the job of each user on this site to keep their questions and answers as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counter example (with the assumption that you meant to equip $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with the uniform measure as in 5xum's comment).

Consider $P = \{(a,b) \in \Bbb N \times \Bbb N \:|\: a \geq b\}$. Then $A_n^b = \{b, \dots, n\}$ if $n \geq b$ and $A_n^b = \emptyset$ if $n < b$. You get $$P(A_n^b) = \frac{n-b + 1}{n} \to 1$$ for $n \to \infty$.

However, $A_n = \{(a,b) \in \{1, \dots, n\} \times \{1,\dots, n\}\:|\: a \geq b\}$ so $A_n$ contains $\frac{1}{2}n (n+1)$ elements so that 
$$ P(A_n) = \frac{n (n+1)}{2 n^2} \to \frac{1}{2} $$
for $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Nice counterexample. Thanks a million. Can we at least expect for a lower bound better than 0?

Comment: If you take take $P_k = \{(a,b) \:|\: a \geq k b\}$ for $k \in \Bbb N$, you should get $\lim_{k \to \infty} \lim_{n\to \infty}P_k(A_n) = 0$, I believe.

Comment: Yes! It's true. Thanks